# Start a process in Powershell v2 with user credentials and a hidden window

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How to do this in Powershell v2.0 ?

```
Start-Process cmd.exe -Credential $MyCred -WindowStyle Hidden;
```

i.e. start a process while giving user credentials and hiding the window.

When i execute each one separately it just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
$cred=Get-Credential
Start-Process cmd.exe -Credential $cred -WindowStyle Hidden
```